# Testing a function returning boolean

Tags: clojure

I have possibly the most simple test failing with a rather confusing message for Clojure newbie.

```
(ns leiningen.booltest
  (:use clojure.test))

(with-test
  (defn bool-function [] 
    (true))

  (is (= (bool-function) true))
)

ERROR in (bool-function) (booltest.clj:10)
expected: (= (bool-function) true)
  actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling true as a function: `(true)` on line 3 of your `with-test` expression. It should simply be `true`, without the surrounding parentheses.

You can further simplify your expression, since `bool-function` already returns `true`:

```
 (with-test
      (defn bool-function [] 
        true)
      (is (bool-function)))
```